# How to use Kotlin to find whether a string is numeric?

Tags: kotlin, types

I'd like to use a `when()` expression in Kotlin to return different values from a function. The input is a `String`, but it might be parsable to an `Int`, so I'd like to return the parsed `Int` if possible, or a `String` if it is not. Since the input is a `String`, I cannot use the is type check expression.

Is there any idiomatic way to achieve that?

My problem is what the `when()` expression should look like, not about the return type.

Comment: Functions can only have 1 return type. Perhaps return `Int?` and make it null if the input wasn't numeric. Or maybe throw an exception if the input wasn't numeric. There are many ways to go about this. --- Look at the `myString.toInt()` extension function.

Comment: @byxor (& Todd) the function may return a generic object with 2 attributes of different types (int / string), one being null depending on the input value type

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear, my problem is how the when expression should look like, not about the return type.

Comment: @uzilan have a look at `toIntOrNull` : https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int-or-null.html

Comment: @rdurand toIntOrNull looks great! Any ideas how to use it in a when expression?

Comment: @uzilan not sure, but this page details use-cases for the `when()` statement : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html

Comment: Why the requirement on a when expression?

Comment: @Todd because I'm trying to learn how to use when :)

Comment: But actually this is not a good use case, you should try to find better scenarios for `when`. It makes sense to apply it on an `Any` function parameter for instance if you want to know what type has been passed as an argument

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**Version 1 (using [`toIntOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int-or-null.html) and `when` as requested)**

```
fun String.intOrString(): Any {
    val v = toIntOrNull()
    return when(v) {
        null -> this
        else -> v
    }
}

"4".intOrString() // 4
"x".intOrString() // x
```

**Version 2 (using [`toIntOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int-or-null.html) and the elvis operator `?:`)**

`when` is actually not the optimal way to handle this, I only used `when` because you explicitly asked for it. This would be more appropriate:

```
fun String.intOrString() = toIntOrNull() ?: this
```

**Version 3 (using exception handling):**

```
fun String.intOrString() = try { // returns Any
   toInt()
} catch(e: NumberFormatException) {
   this
}
```

Comment: Also `toLongOrNull`, `toDoubleOrNull`.

Answer (score 18):

The `toIntOrNull` function in the `kotlin.text` package (in `kotlin-stdlib`) is probably what you're looking for:

> **toIntOrNull**
>
> ```
> fun String.toIntOrNull(): Int? (source)
> ```
>
> Platform and version requirements: Kotlin 1.1
>
> Parses the string as an Int number and returns the result or null if the string is not a valid representation of a number.
>
> ```
> fun String.toIntOrNull(radix: Int): Int? (source)
> ```
>
> Platform and version requirements: Kotlin 1.1
>
> Parses the string as an Int number and returns the result or null if the string is not a valid representation of a number.

More information: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int-or-null.html

Answer (score 9):

Using let for one

```
fun isInteger(str: String?) = str?.toIntOrNull()?.let { true } ?: false
```

Comment: Even if this one is the right answer, it is a general good conduct to explain why this is the answer to follow.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was (and I'm sorry if I was unclear) about using when, since I was trying to understand it at the time.

Comment: @plinh fun isInteger(str: String?) = str?.toIntOrNull() != null

Comment: This is correct but you have to make sure the numbers you are working with are not larger than Integer or this will return false since it cannot convert it into an Int even tho its numeric. To check if a string is numeric you should use Long or Double to make the function work in more scenarios.

Answer (score 8):

Simple and intuitive

```kotlin
fun isNumeric(str: String) = str.all { it in '0'..'9' }
```

As @coolMind point out, if you want to filter +/-

```kotlin
fun isNumeric(str: String): Boolean = str
        .removePrefix("-")
        .removePrefix("+")
        .all { it in '0'..'9' }
```

The performance would be similar

Comment: What I like about this solution is that it does not matter how long the string is. Ints have a max value in Kotlin, which I might want to exceed

Comment: And what if `str` starts with "-" or "+"?

Comment: This was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check if it is numeric (Int) the string and do something a simple solution could be:

```
if (myString.toIntOrNull() != null) {
   //Write your code you want to execute if myString is (Int)
} else {
   //Write your code you want to execute if myString is (not Int)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing [Regex matches](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/matches.html) solution, repost from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69282734/7873768)

Best suited solution if negative and positive number which can be formatted with '-' and '.'

below method returns true if formatted string number matches the regex pattern

```
fun isPosOrNegNumber(s: String?) : Boolean {
    val regex = """^(-)?[0-9]{0,}((\.){1}[0-9]{1,}){0,1}$""".toRegex()
    return if (s.isNullOrEmpty()) false 
           else regex.matches(s)            
}
```

[image]

Above sample regex is only for US number formats but if you want to use EU number formats then just replace '.' with ',' in regex pattern string

Note:. if the numbers contain commas then just replace it while sending to this method or better form a regex pattern with commas in it.

Answer (score -1):

I searched for the same and I found this answer so I have made my own version from the above answer:

```
//function to check strin is int or bull
fun String.intOrString(): Boolean{
    val v = toIntOrNull()
    return when(v) {
       null -> false
        else -> true
    }
}
```