# How to check string has digit only in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working in Kotlin Android.

The string is coming from the server, and it might contain digit, character, empty string or null value. I want to convert that value into double because I want to compare values.

So is there any better way to check that string contains only digit value and not empty or null in a Kotlin way. The list is huge, so I want an efficient way.

**Price.kt**

```
data class Price(
  var value: String? = null
)
```

**main.kt**

```
val defaultValue : Double = 4.23
val list = listOf(Price("2.33"), Price("fr23"), Price(""), Price(null), Price("4.23"), Price("12.23"))

list.forEach{
   if(it == defaultValue){
      println("Found It")
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use a regex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116753/how-to-use-kotlin-when-to-find-if-a-string-is-numeric

Comment: @Zain there is so many way in the answer. Which one is more effective and less expensive

Comment: If your number is not that big, it won't be a big deal you'd go for the simplest

Comment: If you are looking for an exact match, why not just convert your [defaultValue] to String, instead of all other values to Double?

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin already has an efficient solution: [toDoubleOrNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-double-or-null.html)

> Parses the string as a Double number and returns the result or null if
> the string is not a valid representation of a number.

```
if (list.any { it.value.toDobleOrNull() == defaultValue }) {
    println("Found It")
}
```