# Checking if user entered data type int with if else statement Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

**EDIT: ANSWER TO THIS IS BELOW**

Really new to kotlin, wanting to check if user entered an Integer, using if else statement. Need to add a do while loop to it later.

Expecting Error Message: Incorrect

When I hover over (input != pin) it displays
Condition 'input != pin' is always true.

Here's my code

```
fun main() {
println("Create PIN: ")
val pin = readln().toInt()

println("Enter PIN: ")
val input = readln().toInt()

if (input == pin){
    println ("Correct")
}
else if (input != pin) {
    println("Incorrect")
}
}
```

Comment: The extra `if` is unecessary. You can just write `else` without `else if`.

Comment: Apart from that, thats not how you would check that. See the duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116753/how-to-use-kotlin-to-find-whether-a-string-is-numeric i.e. `readln().toIntOrNull()` and then check on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if `input == pin` is false so `input != pin` is always true, that's why you don't need the second else if you can just replace it with if:

```
fun main() {
    println("Create PIN: ")
    val pin = readln().toInt()

    println("Enter PIN: ")
    val input = readln().toInt()

    if (input == pin){
        println ("Correct")
    }
    else {
        println("Incorrect")
    }
}
```

But now if the user enters something that can't be converted to int ( some characters for example "hello"... ) .toInt() is going to throw a `NumberFormatException` and your code is not going to work so to fix that problem and handle the case when a user enters something other that `Int`, you can use `.toIntOrNull()` instead of `.toInt()`.

`.toIntOrNull()`: Parses the string as an Int number and returns the result or null if the string is not a valid representation of a number.

So if pin or input is null, that mean that the user enters something that can't be converted to Int.

```
fun main() {
    println("Create PIN: ")
    val pin = readln().toIntOrNull()

    println("Enter PIN: ")
    val input = readln().toIntOrNull()

    if (input == null || pin == null) {
        println("PIN is not valid")
    }
    else if (input == pin){
        println ("Correct")
    }
    else {
        println("Incorrect")
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg I'm silly of course! but what if user enters another data type? Like a float, double, string?

Comment: @Gilli you are adding .toInt() so the user input is going to be converted to int, and if he enters something that can't be converted to int ( some characters for example "hello"... ) .toInt() is going to throw a NumberFormatException and your code is not going to work

Comment: Sorry guys new to stack overflow, realised my question was already answered above with the .toIntOrNull() CHEERS GUYS! and thanks for your patience.